# Excel `Vlookup` AND `IF` functions

Tags: excel-formula

These are my table:

SheetA

```
      A               B
1    UserID         Time/Date
2    1001           2014-7-1 
3    1002           2014-7-1
4    1001           2014-7-2
5    1001           2014-7-3
6    1002           2014-7-4
          ...etc...
```

SheetB

```
       A         B   
1    UserID:    1002
2    2014-7-1    Y
3    2014-7-2    N
4    2014-7-3    N
5    2014-7-4    Y
         ...etc...
```

I want to check if the UserID (entered manually, B1) in the specific date is absent or not. (with formula, B2:B5)

I used `=vlookup("B1",'sheetA$'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)` but it only returns the date. 
column A of `SheetB` is predefined by typing.

How can I make the formula to check USERID and DATE and return Yes/No

Or any better way for such comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to solve this is to add a 3rd column that concatenates the User ID and Date/Time. So I would add column C in Sheet A with the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)
```

This creates a unique identifier of sorts, which you can then easily use in a VLOOKUP. So in Sheet B, I would then use:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($B$1,A2),SheetA!$C:$C,1,FALSE)),"N","Y")
```

Comment: Thanks, the column should be 2 instead of 3 (typo). In your code, there is no input for comparison of column A.

Comment: Thanks - I missed that. I have amended my answer.

Comment: it is a great idea of using `CONCATENATE`, Thanks.